# Python: Test if string is equal to a datetime object?

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, exception

I'm nearly done with a date-fixing function (my first real project in Python!) and I've gotten a lot of great help through stackoverflow--thank you!

My problem now is testing for a variable that does not conform to the conditions I've stated in my program. Here's what I'm trying to do:

For dates in my program, I want to check against various ways these dates may have been entered (e.g., 01/01/1999, 01-01-1999, 01-Jan-1999, 1/1/1999, 3-9-1999, "None", etc.). What I can't get to work is if a value was entered that is a) not an integer (i.e. 1999), b) not in datetime.date format, or c) not the string 'None'. In my example of the full code below, I can't figure out how to get "WORDS" to hit an exception that says something to the effect that it's not a valid date.

If someone has the time, can you please look at my code and see if you spot an obvious error? I'm thinking I may need something that compares the variable 'date' to whether or not it is a datetime object, and if false, print out a message indicating that it's not a valid date, but multiple attempts to catch this have all been unsuccessful. If anyone has a suggestion, or another article to read or if they can find a question similar (I haven't found one), please let me know. Thank you for your time!

*Also, if the coding is too verbose, please forgive me; first timer!

```
import datetime
import sys
import re

debug = True
log = sys.stdout

dates = ["WORDS", "4-1-2010", "9/1/1999", "7-9-2000", "01/01/2001", "None", "14-Jun-1905", \
"09/09/2009", 2008, "06-06-2006", 1999, "05-May-2005", "12/31/2010", "09-Jul-1905", "07/09/1905", \
"07-09-1905", "1-Jul-1905", "03-Aug-1935", "3/1/1965", 1900]

def fix_date(date):
    constant = datetime.date(1899, 12, 30)
    if debug : print("Fix date:", date, file=log)
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%b-%Y')
    year = int(dt.year)
    month = int(dt.month)
    day = int(dt.day)
    cleanDate = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    dateYear = cleanDate - constant
    x = int(dateYear.days)
    if x < 1901:
        print("ERROR: Date removed:", date, '\n', file=log)
        return ""
    elif x <= datetime.datetime.now().year:
        print("Date converted:", date, "\b:", dateYear.days, file=log)
        print("Date OK:", dateYear.days, '\n')
        return str(dateYear.days)
    else:
        newdate = datetime.datetime.strftime(cleanDate, '%Y%m%d')
        if debug : print("Date OK:", newdate, '\n', file=log)
        return newdate
    print()

print('\nAll Date Variables:\n')
count = 0

for date in dates:
    count += 1
    print(count, '\b: Original date:', date)
    try:
        if date != datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y'):
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y')
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y').strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
            print("DASH:", date)
            fix_date(date)
    except:
        try:
            if date != datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y'):
                dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
                date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
                print("SLASH:", date)
                fix_date(date)
        except:
            try:
                if date != datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%b-%Y'):
                    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%b-%Y')
                    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
                    print("MEDIUM:", date)
                    fix_date(date)
            except:
                try:
                    if date.strip() == "None":
                        print("NONE:", date)
                        print("DO NOT ENTER A DATE\n")
                except:
                    try:
                        if len(str(date)) == 4:
                            print("INTEGER:", date)
                            print("Date OK:", str(date), '\n')
                    except:
                        print("SOME ERROR OCCURRED")
```

*EDIT*

I got things to work by altering the code slightly and making an "else" statement in the block before the last try/except block. Easier to see my edit by looking for the trail of stars :)

```
...
                try:
                    if date.strip() == "None":
                        print("NONE:", date)
                        print("DO NOT ENTER A DATE\n")
                    else:
                        print("********************INVALID DATE")
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something a bit better.  Rather than trying all the formats yourself, use the dateutil.  One line of code to try and parse the date.

You'll need the dateutil pip package

```
import dateutil
from dateutil import parser

dte = dateutil.parser.parse('03-31-1981');
dte = dateutil.parser.parse('03/31/1981');
dte = dateutil.parser.parse('1981-03-31');
dte = dateutil.parser.parse('1981-MAR-31');
print(dte)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll look through dateutil; will this also help identify variable dates that aren't in a specific format, or would that just be handled now with a simple if/else statement?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Per your previous suggestion with the else statement, I went back. It appears that it works if I put it in the next-to-last try/if statement...weird. Any idea why?

    `code`
    ...
    if date.strip() == "None":
        print("NONE:", date)
        print("DO NOT ENTER A DATE\n")
    else:
        print("INVALID DATE\n")
    ...
    `code`

Comment: Messing around with dateutil briefly, there could be a world of new formats that it may work with. Will definitely play with this. Thank you!

Comment: *Update:
the dateutil suggestion was huge. Thank you!

Comment: Very glad to help... appreciate if u can upvote if that's possible